# invalid column name error when writing pandas DataFrame to sql

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymssql

When I try to write a dataframe to ms sql server, like this:

```
cnxn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@HOST:PORT/DATABASE?driver=SQL+Server") 
df.to_sql('DATABASE.dbo.TABLENAME', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'DateDay'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO [DATABASE.dbo.TABLENAME] ([DateDay], [ID], [Code], [Forecasted], [Lower95CI], [Upper95CI], [ForecastMethod], [ForecastDate]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ((datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 10, 0, 0), '8496', "'IO'", 197, 138, 138, 'ARIMAX',...
```

it seems that the column name is producing the error? it is looking for [DateDay] but it finds 'DateDay' with the ' '? how to fix this?

I am using python 3.6 on a windows machine, pandas 0.22, sqlalchemy 1.1.13 and pyodbc 4.0.17

**UPDATE-- SOLUTION FOUND:**

So I realized that my mistake was in the tablename which calls the database: 'DATABASE.dbo.TABLENAME', when i removed the DATABASE.dbo, it worked:

```
df.to_sql('TABLENAME', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: What does df.columns have?  Are quotes in your column headings?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I added the database name when executing the df.to_sql command, which was not needed since I had already established a connection to that database. This worked:

```
df.to_sql('TABLENAME', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem also may happen if the name you defined in the database table and the name you defined in the dataframe for the same column is different. For example, 'items' and 'itens' will not match and this will cause an error when your script tries to record the dataframe into the database.