# Import .csv into local SQL server with pre-made table using Python

Tags: sql-server, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm making (or trying to) make a small script that compiles two .csvs, drops duplicates, then uploads itself to my local MS SQL server. I already have the table made, and I'd prefer it that way, as I need to be able to tweak the server and it's much, much easier doing that through SQL. I'm still very new to Python and don't know too much more about SQL but this site has been supremely helpful so far.

I have the .csv output and connecting to the database down (I think) but I can't get it to pull my .csv and input it into the database. I've tried a ton of different ways suggested here, but I think I'm too much of a novice to recognize what I'm doing, so it's difficult to be certain. I need the columns of the database to be put in the same columns in the SQL server. Column 'side' is the primary key in SQL. All other values are NOT NULL.

Depending on what I try, I'll either get no errors, but no input, or I'll get some sort of error. With the current code below, I get kicked back, stating that all of my columns are invalid.
A few times I've been able to input incorrect values, or just a single line. That was with the BULK INSERT command, and if I add more lines, it stops working, so I've taken a different approach.

Please ignore the extraneous modules I've imported. Once I figure this out, and get my code working properly, I'll remove the ones I don't need.

I've tried pymssql but ran into an issue linking it properly to the database, I've tried just a simple cursor command for INSERT INTO with no luck either.

I've tried this from this question here:
[Import CSV file into SQL Server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899088/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-python)
and here
[Pandas - CSV to SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219015/pandas-csv-to-sql-database)

but many of these are difficult as they include the creation of a database in Python and not SQL server. Eventually I want this compiled into a small .exe that my coworkers can use and I'd rather just be able to change the SQL server instead of having to redistribute a new app version every time there's a change in the table. The values inputted will stay the same, but calculations will change and different columns (surrounding these columns here) will come and go.

Here is a small snippet of example code, showing just the portion that doesn't work correctly.

```
from six.moves import urllib
import csv
import pymssql
import d6tstack

#Create Engine
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=SERVER;"
                      "Database=AppDev;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "TrustServerCertificate=yes"
                      )
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params) 
engine.connect() 



#Connect to SQL Database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=SERVER;"
                      "Database=AppDev;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "TrustServerCertificate=yes"
                      )
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#######################################################Importing Files(WIP)################################################################################

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:PATHFullOutput.csv", index_col=False)


df.to_sql("Wolverine",engine, if_exists='append',chunksize=300,dtype={'Serial': String(22),
                                                                     } 
        )

             
cnxn.commit()


#closes connection
cnxn.close()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'index'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Serial'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'index'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Serial'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [Wolverine] ([index], [Serial]) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)]
[parameters: (0, 'FPNLCB804MRK0223179054', 1, 'FPNLCB804MRK0223179054')]
```

In my code to create the .csv I specifically have it set to not create an index, and there is not visible index in the output .csv, so the fact that there is an invalid column titled 'Index' is an issue as well.

Please let me know where I've gone wrong, I'm sure it's more than once, haha. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest trying to come up with a minimal reproducible example to edit into your question instead of all that code, i.e.: whittle it down to just loading a single CSV file into a SQL Server table. One thing I'll point out is that SQLAlchemy has its own function to create URLs for create_engine(), so maybe try using that instead. A second thing I'll point out is that you're referencing pyodbc, so have you checked its autocommit behaviour? A third thing I'll point out is that you're using the dead-and-buried SQL Server Native Client driver, try using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (or 18).

Comment: When you get stuck, simplify your code to the bare minimum. Comment out all the code that works, manually make a simple CSV file with one column and one row (do you need to include column headers in CSV?), adjust your `df.to_sql` to use only one column. Run it and see what happens. If you get errors post it here (by updating your original question)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the response! This was very helpful. I upgraded to Driver 18, and made myself a certificate through OpenSSL so the server will talk to my program. I've updated my code snippet to a simplified version using just the portion that doesn't work. Alex, thanks for your advice as well. I'm getting a similar error, and it's trying to add an index column even though I have index=false when creating the .csv

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669373/invalid-column-name-error-when-writing-pandas-dataframe-to-sql

Comment: @Alex I actually already had that in my source code. I played around with it this morning and changed literally nothing and now it works perfectly. Weird. Thanks for your help, closing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out. With Pandas/SQL Alchemy, you can't get your datatypes to match up with MS SQL Server. What worked for me is deleting the table, and just running the python code, creating a new table. If I want to add columns or a primary key, I can do so after the table is created through SQL Alchemy. Works like a charm every time. Don't waste time fooling around, wondering if your double or single quotes are the issue. Just get Python to make the table and change it in SQL to your liking afterward.

Comment: Why are you booing me? I'm right! And no one else had an answer, either.